# Перевести на русский ошибки выводимые при регистрации. Модул django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Для авторизации и регистрации использую модуль django-allauth.
Подскажите, как сделать перевод сообщений об ошибках на русский язык.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]